# How to print multidimensional array when its key is a string?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array ( 
    [Team1] => Array ( 
        [win] => 1 
        [draw] => 0 
        [lost] => 0 
    ) 
    [Team2] => Array ( 
        [win] => 1 
        [draw] => 1 
        [lost] => 1 
    ) 
    [Team3] => Array ( 
        [win] => 1 
        [draw] => 0 
        [lost] => 1 
    ) 
    [AnotherTeam] => Array ( 
        [win] => 0 
        [draw] => 0 
        [lost] => 1 
    ) 
    [LastTeam] => Array ( 
        [win] => 0 
        [draw] => 1 
        [lost] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

Above is an example of a generated array. Imagine there are some football clubs with their win draw and lost number of games.

I would like to print this array as rows and columns of a table like following;

```
Team   |  Win |  Draw  |  Lost
Team 1    1      0        0
Team 2    1      1        1
```

I had an advice to use extract method. But didn't figure out well. Hope anyone can give me a clue.

Thanks,

Comment: `array_keys($yourArray[0])` should give you the array of header. Just iterate over this array to print the header. Finally iterate of the initial array `$yourArray` to print the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$teamArr=Array ('Team1' => Array ('win' => 1 ,'draw' => 0,'lost' => 0),
'Team2' => Array ('win' => 1 ,'draw' => 0,'lost' => 0) ,
'Team3' => Array ('win' => 1 ,'draw' => 0,'lost' => 0),
'Another team' => Array ('win' => 1 ,'draw' => 0,'lost' => 0),
'Last Team' => Array ('win' => 1 ,'draw' => 0,'lost' => 0));

echo '<table width=100%><tr><th>Teams</th><th>Win</th><th>Draw</th><th>Lost</th> </tr>';
foreach($teamArr as $key => $value) {

 echo "<tr> <th>$key</th>";
        foreach($value as $status) {
          echo "<th>$status</th>";
        }
 echo "</tr>";

}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<table><tr><th>Teams</th><th>Win</th><th>Draw</th><th>Lost</th></tr>';
foreach($teamsArray as $key => $value) {

 echo "<tr> <td>$key</td>";
            foreach($value as $status) {
              echo "<td>$status</td>";
            }
 echo "</tr>";

}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Initially `$teamArray` has the set of all values. With that key value, it creates a new row of record like `[Team1]` and `$value` also contains another array. For that , loop the status of `table data` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<table>
<tr><td>Team</td><td>Win</td><td>Draw</td><td>Lost</td></tr>
<?php foreach($your_array as $key=>$val){ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $key;?></td><td><?php echo $val['win'];?></td><td><?php echo $val['draw'];?></td><td><?php echo $val['lost'];?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```